# Problem inserting an image

Tags: graphics

I am using `\includegraphics` to insert an image, the image is appearing in text but some part of file name and .jpg are also appearing in the text (like `a.jpg`) how can I remove it? why is `a.png` shown in text?

How can I code this flowchart and add it to text directly without inserting it to text?

[image: picture]

Comment: It seems your file name has spaces. Remove those spaces and try again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems that your problem has already been dealt with here. If the linked message helps you, fine; otherwise, please, comment about it.